# ps not fount when attaching .Net Core WebApi to Docker container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, dockerfile

I am trying to debug my .Net Core webApi project using Docker. However, I am struggling to make it work.

I was following this [link](https://dev.to/azure/debugging-your-net-core-in-docker-applications-with-vs-code-3g5d), to attached my .Net Core app on Docker using VS Code.

This is my **Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env

#install debugger for NET Core
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y procps && \
    curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | /bin/sh /dev/stdin -v latest -l /vsdbg

WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BooksApi.dll"]
```

Then, I added the **launch.json** in order to attached the Docker container process:

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickRemoteProcess}",
            "pipeTransport": {
                "pipeProgram": "docker",
                "pipeArgs": ["exec", "-i", "forecastapp"],
                "debuggerPath": "/vsdbg/vsdbg",
                "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "quoteArgs": false
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/app": "${workspaceRoot}"
            }
        }
]
```

Those two files seems to be fine at first glance. So when building and running it on Docker everything is OK.

Docker build command:

```
docker build -t myweatherforecastapp .
```

Docker run command

```
docker run -it -p 8080:80 --name forecastapp myweatherforecastapp
```

Until this point everything is working fine. I can hit the end point.

[image]

[image]

So, the docker container is running. Now I want to **attached** it using **Visual Studio Code**. When I click on the green arrow on the debug option:

[image]

I am getting this error:

[image]

When googling the error, I saw that we need to install procps using apt install ([link](https://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2019-05-17-fixing-cant-connect-to-docker-debugger/)). That's already covered on my Dockerfile:

```
 apt install -y procps
```

I am kind of running out of ideas what might be wrong or if I am missing something. Could you help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed package in the base image, while it should be installed in the final image where you are going to use `ps`.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y procps
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BooksApi.dll"]
```

Build and test

```
docker build -t myapp .
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint bash myapp
ps
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did the modification and it worked. I can attached the container to my VS Code. The only problem I am facing now, is that despite the fact I set a breakpoint, it didn't stop there. It says no symbols has been loaded. I guess that is a different issue I need to troubleshoot.