# Docker container - no symbols have been loaded for this document

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I already have my Visual Studio Code attached to my running container. It's a .Net Core WepApi. This is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62905166/ps-not-fount-when-attaching-net-core-webapi-to-docker-container/62905958#62905958) for the post I created when struggling to make it work.

The problem, I am facing now, is that despite the fact my VS Code is attached to the container I can't debug any code yet. It keeps saying:

**No symbols has been loaded for this document**

Which is kind of odd because I can see the pdb files where generated and deploy to the container:

[image]

When I attached the Docker Container my VS Code looks like this:

[image]

This is the updated docker file I have:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out


###########START NEW IMAGE###########################################
# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1

#install debugger for NET Core
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y unzip procps && \
    curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | /bin/sh /dev/stdin -v latest -l /vsdbg

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BooksApi.dll"]
```

Has anyone have face a similar problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?
Suddenly my working project is giving the same issue.

Comment: For me adding debug type portable fixed the problem.

Also, previous I had no debugtype in csproj in .net core 3.1 but debugging was working.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue but my project is in .NET7. Same thing, pdb is in the container, attached to process but no symbols loaded. I tried adding debug type portable but no result for me.